# Light in a box with positron walls instead of electrons

Tags: visible-light, reflection, antimatter

I understand that with a hollow cube with the inner walls covered in mirrors given a light source briefly, the light would eventually be absorbed. This is due to electron excitation I believe. So suppose the cube had walls of positrons instead of mirrors, since there are no electrons what would happen?

Comment: The interaction of low energy photons with positrons is the same as with electrons, so all the relevant effects would be exactly the same. Curious, though, why you think it would make a difference?

Comment: It's actually a good question and physically highly relevant. I was merely wondering what pointed you to it. If you were just asking out of naive curiosity, I have to congratulate you to the quality of your naive curiosity. It knows how to ask the right questions!

Comment: Oh just curiosity, CuriousOne :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm imagining a box made completely out of anti-matter so that your situation is realistic.

Positrons are the antiparticle of the electron (i.e., the anti-matter equivalent). Meaning, in this case, they're identical to electrons except for charge.

Photons, though, have no charge. So don't give a hoot whether a charged particle it's interacting with is positive or negative; the resulting interaction will be the same regardless.